# Extend UI select controller (angular)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, inheritance, decorator, angular-ui-select

I'm trying to extend the ui-select (version 0.17.1) to make it refresh on click. There is this example here (https://jsfiddle.net/betonetotbo/0yfhe7pf/) that I've been using as a starting point.

I want this to happen app-wide so I replaced the ui-select-choices directive html with my own which includes a div button. I also added a decorator to replace the directives controller with a new one which is not yet defined.

```
myapp.app.config(function(provide) {
    $provide.decorator("uiSelectDirective", [ "$delegate", "uiSelectConfig", "$controller"], function ($delegate, uiSelectConfig, $controller) {
        var directive = $delegate[0];
        // This line throws error Unknown provider
        var $select = $controller('uiSelectCtrl');

        return $delegate;
    }]);
});
```

My problem is that I also want to decorate/extend the controller to add the extra functionality throughout the application. I don't want to re-write it in it's entirety so I'm looking for the proper way to extend a controller such as this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved this problem by overloading the directive's compile method:

```
$provide.decorator('uiSelectDirective', ['$delegate', function ($delegate) {
    var directive = $delegate[0];
    var compile = directive.compile;

    directive.compile = function (tElement, tAttrs) {
        var link = compile.apply(this, arguments);
        return function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
            link.apply(this, arguments);
            var ctrl = ngModel[0];
            var activate = ctrl.activate;

            //I had to close the dropdown when clicking on the directive
            ctrl.activate = function (initSearchValue, avoidReset) {
                if (!ctrl.disabled) {
                    if (ctrl.open) {
                        ctrl.close();
                    } else {
                        activate(initSearchValue, avoidReset);
                    }
                }
            }
        };
    };

    return $delegate;
}]);
```